# Reference private resources in paper

Tags: citations, computer-science

Some of the deliverables of a project I'm working on are of a private nature (due to commercial reasons) and will not be released to the public. Would it be acceptable for a (conference or) workshop paper to reference one of those deliverables?

To give some more background, part of an algorithm on my paper is based on work described on one of those *private* documents. I need to acknowledge that somehow.

Comment: Are the deliverables of private nature due to national security reasons (as opposed to other reasons, e.g., commercial IP)?

Comment: @MadJack: Some deliverables are of private nature due to commercial reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> part of an algorithm on my paper is based on work described on one of those private documents. I need to acknowledge that somehow.

The algorithm has not previously been published, so you can claim that it is an original contribution of your paper. You can acknowledge the project in your acknowledgements section.

Problems might arise if your paper and the private document have different authors. In this case, you should seek permission from those authors to publish your paper and you should acknowledge the contribution of those authors.